# Edge Constraint satisfaction in a Directed Graph Path?

Tags: algorithms, graphs

Given a directed Graph and two vertices $S$ and $D$ (source and destination) such that each of its edges has a weight of the form:

$A_i+B_ix_i = V$

where $A_0$ is a non negative integer, $B_0$ is a positive integer, $x_i$ a variable that can take non negative integer values (each variable used only once in the graph).

Find a positive value $V$ such that it there exists a path from $S$ to $D$ in Graph such that $V$ satisfies all edges in that path.

Of course the trivial method would be testing each positive integer value of $V$. But this might take an exponential time. Is there something better we can do to achieve the solution in polynomial time, or that is the best we have ?

Comment: Something is missing here - what happens with the variables $x_i$? Are you looking for a value $V$, an assignment to the variables $x_i$, and an $S$-to-$D$ path such that all constraints along the edges of the path are satisfied? If so, you should update the question to make it clear. Perhaps you want all constraints on *all* paths to be satisfied?

Comment: Are you interested in knowing whether a value $V$ exists, or in actually finding it? What if $V$ is very large?

Comment: The variables $x_i$ is unique for each edge ($i$ being say the edge number).  A value $V$ that satisfies _one of the paths_ (all edges in it) from $S$ to $D$ (either finding it or saying one exists would be fine i suppose). The problem is $V$ can be very large, otherwise we can test all its values one at a time. (if you want please go ahead an edit to make it clearer as you please).

Comment: The first step would be to come up with a criterion for a set of constraints $A_i + B_ix_i = V$ to be jointly satisfiable. By assuming that $V$ is large enough, such a constraint just states that $V \equiv A_i \pmod{B_i}$. Two such constraints are contradictory iff $A_i \not\equiv A_j \pmod{(B_i,B_j)}$.

Comment: I agree. I think (not sure as of now):  a set of constraints $A_i + B_ix_i = V$ will be satisfiable iff there are no two constraints in the set such that: if $B_i$'s have a common factor > 1, and their corresponding $A_i$'s are not equal.

Comment: I was just typing..:) You are correct in stating the contradiction condition (mine is flawed). But, the problem is there are exponential number of potential paths or such sets. So, i am unsure how to proceed next.

Comment: Well, this reduces your problem to one which is much cleaner, and in particular, doesn't mention any number-theoretic constraints.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assume first that the $x_i$ can take any arbitrary values. Then the constraint $A_i + B_i x_i = V$ just states that $V \equiv A_i \pmod{B_i}$. Two such constraints are contradictory if $A_i\not\equiv A_j \pmod{(B_i,B_j)}$, where $(B_i,B_j)$ is the GCD of $B_i$ and $B_j$. The Chinese Remainder Theorem should show (after some work) that any set of constraints in which no two are contradictory can be simultaneously satisfied. (Prove or refute!)

The constraint that $x_i \geq 0$ doesn't actually impose any further constraints. Indeed, take a solution $V$ to the original problem. By adding to $V$ a large enough multiply of $\prod_i B_i$, we obtain another solution in which all $x_i$ are non-negative.

This reduces your problem to the following problem:

> Given a directed graph and a set of forbidden pairs of edges, does there exist a path from $s$ to $t$ that doesn't contain a forbidden pair of edges?

Unfortunately, this problem is NP-complete, by reduction from SAT. Given $m$ clauses $\varphi_1,\ldots,\varphi_m$, there will be $m+1$ vertices $v_0,\ldots,v_m$. For each literal $\ell \in \varphi_i$, there is a corresponding edge from $v_{i-1}$ to $v_i$. Two complementary literals form a forbidden pair. A legal path from $v_0$ to $v_m$ exists iff the instance is satisfiable.

There are now two options:

- Either your particular instance has more structure, which you can employ to get a more efficient solution;
- Or your original problem is also NP-hard.

Comment: Path with forbidden pairs. NP Complete reduction from 3SAT. I remeber this one. thanks.

Comment: You beat me to it!

Comment: but you did help the reduction. P.S. Why on earth is every interesting problem NPComplete (rhetorical frustration) :)

Answer (score 1):

Building on [Yuval's answer](https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/76684/755), your problem is NP-complete.  Yuval shows a reduction from your problem to the forbidden-pairs path problem, and from there to SAT.  However as Yuval says this doesn't immediately prove that your problem is NP-complete, as the reduction goes the wrong way.  I'll show a reduction in the other direction, thus proving that your problem is NP-complete.

Let $\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_m$ be the clauses of a SAT instance on the variables $u_1,\dots,u_n$.  Let $p_1,\dots,p_m$ denote the first $m$ primes.  We'll have $m+1$ vertices, $v_0,\dots,v_m$.  The edges are as follows:

- For each positive literal $u_j$ that appears in $\varphi_i$, there will be a corresponding edge from $v_{i-1}$ to $v_i$, labelled with the constraint $V = 1 \pmod{p_j}$.
- For each negative literal $\neg u_j$ that appears in $\varphi_i$, there will be a corresponding edge from $v_{i-1}$ to $v_i$, labelled with the constraint $V = 0 \pmod{p_j}$.

Now note that if there is a satisfying assignment to the SAT formula, then there is a valid path through this graph: in each clause, we pick one of the literals that is satisfied (there will always be at least one, if this is a satisfying assignment to the SAT formula), and use that to derive a path.  The path will be valid, because we can set $V$ to be a value such that $V = u_1 \pmod{p_1}$, ..., $V = u_n \pmod{p_n}$ (the Chinese remainder theorem guarantees such a $V$ will exist), and then all of the edge constraints will be satisfied.

Conversely, if we have a valid path through this graph, then we can read off a satisfying assignment to the SAT formula: use $V \bmod p_j$ as the value of the variable $u_j$ (i.e., set $u_j$ to true if $V = 1 \pmod{p_j}$, or false otherwise), and then the structure of the graph ensures that this will satisfy at least one literal in each clause of the SAT formula.

This completes the reduction.